# Unity UI Dragging

Tags: unity3d, ui, drag-n-drop

Проблема в том, что у меня просто игнорируются

`public void BeginDrag()`
и
`public void OnDrag()`

я там внутри еще ничего не делаю. Только выдаю сообщения через Debug.Log();
Уже перерыл все что можно было перерыть. Всюду делают через эти 2 функци.. для GUI используется `OnMouseDrag()`, что я, на всякий случай, так же перепровирил с `UI` и так же ноль реакции.

Сам канвас отображается нормально. Кнопки канваса реагируют на наведение мышки и на клик. Пробовал асайнить скрипт как на кнопки, так и просто на панель. Реакции - ноль.

Юнити последний.

Есть у кого идеи?

Comment: А что с камерами? Сколько у вас камер на сцене? Попробуйте удалить лишние

Comment: 1на камера на сцене. Формально, только камера и канвас с кнопками/панелями.

Comment: Какая платформа?

Comment: А IDragHandler имплиментирует класс? Здесь можно глянуть как должно выглядеть определение - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.ScrollRect.OnDrag.html

Comment: @MikhailEfremov, спасибо большое, причина оказалась именно в этом. Но в то же время странно, я находил 3-4 готовых скрипта которые работали у других людей и у меня они не сработали.... В любом случае, запость ответ, что бы я отметил как верный. Всем остальным так же спасибо за участие!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы методов BeginDrag(), OnDrag() и OnEndDrag(), нужно имплементировать интерфейсы [IBeginDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IBeginDragHandler.html), [IDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html) и [IEndDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IEndDragHandler.html) соответственно.

Определение класса, принимающее все методы будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragHandler : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
    {
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще как вариант можно добавить на объект EventTrigger и для каждого события назначить вызов метода в требуемом скрипте. Тоже отлично работает, плюс дает возможность настраивать вызов когда он действительно требуется.

Когда метод выглядит вот так(в качестве аргумента `BaseEventData`), в триггере он станет доступен для вызова.

```
    public void OnDrag(UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData)
    {
        var pointerData = eventData as UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData;
        if (pointerData == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Vector3 curPos = rect.position;
        curPos.x += pointerData.delta.x;
        curPos.y += pointerData.delta.y;

        rect.position = curPos;
    }
```